# Using axios inside custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios

I want to create a global axios instance with an interceptor which adds a header with access token.
The access token is stored in a cookie, but I can't figure out how to access the cookie inside the interceptor as it is not a react component.

I have tried creating the axios instance in a custom hook like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import axios from "axios";

function useApiClient() {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setClient(
      axios
        .create({
          baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
          responseType: "json",
        })
        .interceptors.request.use(
          (config) => {
            console.log("setting up");
            if (cookies["token"] != null) {
              config.headers.authorization = cookies["token"];
            }
          },
          (error) => Promise.reject(error)
        )
    );
  }, [client]);

  return client;
}

export default useApiClient;
```

But when I try to call this using:

```
const client = useApiClient();

function attemptLogin() {
    const credentials = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    };

    client
      .post("/authenticate", JSON.stringify(credentials), {
         headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
       }).then(....)
```

I get below error:

> TypeError: client.post is not a function

Can anyone help?

Comment: One problem I notice is that you need to client dependency like this in an array: `[client]` in the useEffect. Also can you show how do you use client.post?

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah 
Than you for your comment. I have tried adding the dependency in an array, but no luck.
I have edited my question to show how i'm using the client.

Comment: have you considered the option of `withCredentials: true` for the axios config?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to use `react-cookie` that provides an api for working with cookies in components. It may be fine for some cases, but for the case when you need to check cookies on every request it forces putting an `axios` instance somewhere at the top of components hierarchy and also makes it harder to use the instance out of components (most likely you'll pass the instance to outer functions).

What I suggest is to make an instance in a separate module, and use a different tool for getting cookies like [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie).

```
// apiClient.js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();

export const apiClient = axios
  .create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
    responseType: "json"
  })
  .interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      console.log("setting up");
      const token = cookies.get("token");
      if (token != null) {
        config.headers.authorization = token;
      }
    },
    error => Promise.reject(error)
  );
```

After that, you can use this instance everywhere in the app

```
import React from 'react';
import { apiClient } from "./apiClient";

export default ({ name }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiClient.get(/*...*/).then(/*...*/);
  });

  return <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
}
```

If you prefer to stick to hooks you could wrap a client into one easily:

```
// apiClient.js
export function useApiClient() { return apiClient; }
```

[Playgroung with full example](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react?file=Hello.js)

Answer (score 0):

That is maybe because `useEffect` in `useApiClient.js` is async method.

Personally I see no harm in directly assigning headers to `axios` object. However I see you are using `axios.create` so I would assume you may be making calls to multiple Service APIs/endpoints and all do not need same headers. Anyways...

**Suggestions**

1. Make `useApiClient` a simple class which returns instance of `axios` with required headers. If not, I am seriously missing the point of using `useEffect` here.

**Behavior**

In each file you file call this and all will have separate instances of `axios` without polluting the global `axios` object.

`useApiClient.js`

```
    function useApiClient {
        return axios
          .create({
            baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
            responseType: "json"
        })
        .interceptors.request.use(
          config => {
            console.log("setting up");
            const token = cookies.get("token");
            if (token != null) {
              config.headers.authorization = token;
            }
          },
          error => Promise.reject(error)
        );
      }
    }

    export default useApiClient;
```

2. Make a Factory Class which returns `axios` instances based on the input parameter (to assign different headers based on parameter passed and return the instance). You may also have it as `Singleton` if feasible.

Hope it helps.